# How To get iOS 6 UITableView Grouped Style in IOS 7

Tags: ios7

I want to get the iOS 6 Look and feel for Grouped UITableView in iOS 7. I dont want to submit builds using Xcode 4.6. I want to submit apps using xcode 5

Comment: You have to fully customize it

Comment: make use of View layer property for adding roundrect features to ur table.

Answer (score 1):

once the iOS7 came with the new tables look, you really should use it. In my projects - I switched my tables to non-grouped style, that looks fine.
At all - you should not breach the Apple design guides - you will have your life more and more difficult ;)